# Porque o lenght do array está como undefined?

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando contar o tamanho de um array e o lenght dele dá como undefined.

Porque?

```
('body').on('click', "#btnGravar", function() {

  $("input:checked").each(function() {
    var infoPedidos = [];
    var classes = $(this).attr("class");
    var value = $(this).data("id");

    if (classes !== undefined && value !== undefined) {
      var idColaborador = $("#cmbColaboradores").val();
      var id = $(this).data("id");
      var protocolo = $(this).data("protocolo");
      var sistema = $(this).data("sistema");
      var equipe = $(this).data("equipe");
      var finalidade = $(this).data("finalidade");
      var fornecedor = $(this).data("fornecedor");

      infoPedidos.push({
        id: id,
        protocolo: protocolo,
        sistema: sistema,
        equipe: equipe,
        finalidade: finalidade,
        fornecedor: fornecedor
      })

      console.log(infoPedidos.lenght);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe é [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) e não `.lenght`.

Comment: Caramba, será que é cansaço por não ter visto isso? ;(

Comment: É normal :) Acontece a toda a gente, os erros mais simples são os mais difíceis de encontrar.